# Django: how can i add a field in admin that has a link to another model admin when using modelform?

Tags: django, admin, modelform

in tabular admin, i want to provide direct link to editing a model which is in a foreignkey of my record.
it works fine when i explicitly defined the admin fields, using reverseurl, like this:

```
class MediaInline(admin.TabularInline):
  fieldsets = [
    (None, {'fields': ['media', 'media_id',...
  ]
  readonly_fields = ['media_id']
  ...


  def media_id(self, object):
      url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' %(object._meta.app_label,  'medialinks'),  args=[object.media.id] )
      return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' %(url,  object.media.id)
  media_id.allow_tags = True
```

But, now i want to define the tabular using a form and i did not find how can do it anymore. i have the HTMl tag as a string but i did not find a way to see it as an HTML tag.

btw, The reason i need a form and not an explicit definition is that i want to be able to order another dropdown field in this tabular list and the only way i found how to do that is in form setting.

Answer (score 0):

A modelform should not prevent you from doing this.

Make sure you don't move this code. You can't put field override code inside a ModelForm.

You use a ModelForm *and* have the overrides in the ModelAdmin (TabularInline).

Comment: i also dont see the "+" sign to add a new record in the media table. is there a way to solve that?

Comment: That means you either don't have permissions, or there's no modeladmin in place to add that model.

Comment: i have permission and there is a modeladmin. if i set my tabularadmin to work with the modelform - then there is no + sign. If i do not use the modelform, then i have the + sign.